# How to use OpenMPI custom datatypes once declared?

Tags: fortran, mpi, fortran90, openmpi, custom-data-type

I want to broadcast non memory contiguous variables (INTEGERS and REAL(8)) from my master process to all the other processes in an MPI FORTRAN90 implementation but since it is my first try at both FORTRAN and MPI (I am only used to C/C++), I have few questions:

- At the moment I use the MPI_TYPE_CREATE_STRUCT call but I know I could also use MPI_PACK/MPI_UNPACK calls which require additional memory-to-memory copy operations. Since the data to broadcast is not that big in this case, what solution offers the best performances? Is there any other solution that I do not know and which are faster/simpler to implement (maybe one MPI_BCAST call per variable?)?
- In the case of a custom MPI datatype, how do I declare a variable (or here a group of a known datatype variables) to be only one variable of a new datatype? I mean now that my MPI structure PARAMETER_READ is created (see code below), how do I tell to the compiler that I want all my variables (nmin, dout, nmax, ncellsmax, ncells, ns, dt, del) stored in the memory to be grouped all together to become only one new variable of type PARAMETER_READ?
- Where do I declare my custom datatypes? Should I declare them inside a:

  IF(rank==0) THEN

  *declaration of the new datatype*

  ENDIF

loop or outside?

Here is my code (I only kept the interesting parts):

```
PROGRAM SIM_3D
USE IO
USE MPI_MOD

IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER :: nmin, dout, nmax, ncellsmax
INTEGER, DIMENSION(3) :: ncells, ns
REAL(8) :: dt,
REAL(8), DIMENSION(3) :: del

CALL init_MPI

IF(rank == master) THEN
  CALL readParams(ncells, del, nmin, dout, nmax, dt, ns, ncellsmax) ! All these values are read by the master process in an external *.txt file using a custom subroutine readParams in the IO module.
  CALL BCAST_PARAM
ENDIF

END PROGRAM SIM_3D
```

Where MPI_MOD is:

```
MODULE MPI_MOD

USE MPI

INTEGER, PARAMETER :: master = 0
INTEGER :: ierror, rank, num_proc
INTEGER, DIMENSION( MPI_STATUS_SIZE ) :: status

INTEGER :: NUMBER_OF_BLOCKS = 2
INTEGER, DIMENSION(2) :: ARRAY_OF_BLOCKLENGTHS = (/ 10, 4/)
INTEGER, DIMENSION(2) :: ARRAY_OF_DISPLACEMENTS = (/ 40, 32/)
INTEGER, DIMENSION(2) :: ARRAY_OF_TYPES = (/ MPI_INTEGER, MPI_REAL/)

CONTAINS

SUBROUTINE init_MPI
  IMPLICIT NONE
  CALL MPI_INIT(ierror)
  CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,rank,ierror)
  CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,num_proc,ierror)
END SUBROUTINE init_MPI

SUBROUTINE BCAST_PARAM
  IMPLICIT NONE
  CALL MPI_TYPE_CREATE_STRUCT(NUMBER_OF_BLOCKS, ARRAY_OF_BLOCKLENGTHS, ARRAY_OF_DISPLACEMENTS, ARRAY_OF_TYPES, PARAMETER_READ, IERROR)
  CALL MPI_TYPE_COMMIT (PARAMETER_READ, IERROR)
  *I would like to put all the variables to be sent in a PARAMETER_READ type variable called BUFFER*
  CALL MPI_BCAST(BUFFER,1,PARAMETER_READ,master,MPI_COMM_WORLD,IERROR)
END SUBROUTINE BCAST_PARAM

END MODULE MPI_MOD
```

I am not even sure that my custom datatype declaration is correct...
Thank you very much for having read me, your help would be very appreciated.
Best regards.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by your second bulletpoint? Will you be communicating these variables several times throughout your code?

Comment: Hi Yossarian, and thank you for your quick answer. I tried to be as clear as I could with my second bulletpoint, I hope it will be enough for you to understand my issue.
Thanks for helping!

Comment: What you're after is Fortran derived types. I've added this to my answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the time you dedicate to that topic.

I'm afraid I haven't been clear enough. Actually I do want to communicate all the variables previously mentionned to all the nodes of the cluster using an MPI routine but I would like to use only one `MPI_BCAST` call that's why I want to 'pack' -or something equivalent- the data in only one variable which could be used in `MPI_BCAST`. In that case why don't you recommend the use of an MPI custom datatype with `MPI_TYPE_CREATE_STRUCT`?

Comment: I have another similar question:

since I am using a Cartesian topology in my code, I would like to use `MPI_CREATE_DARRAY` to communicate to each node a 3D array, created from a part of bigger source 3D array, which contains the data that it has to treat. Once my MPI custom datatype is created, how do I use it and declare all my sub-arrays? In fact I don't know how to use MPI custom datatypes once they are created, how to affect values to variables of that new type.

Comment: To be clear, to use the MPI datatype `PARAMETER_READ` in your question, you also need to create the equivalent Fortran derived type - this is `parameter_read_type` in my answer. Fortran doesn't know about the MPI datatype and MPI doesn't know about the Fortran type,  so you have to use the two together. You declare a Fortran variable to be a `parameter_read_type`, assign your data to its components, then you can use `MPI_BCAST` with `PARAMETER_READ` to communicate it to the rest of the processes.

Comment: I also noticed a bug in your code: `ARRAY_OF_DISPLACEMENTS = (/ 40, 32/)` should be `ARRAY_OF_DISPLACEMENTS = (/ 0, 40/)`.

Comment: Ok thank you very much now I understand. I think it was the point I was missing so far. So: Fortran datatypes and MPI datatypes are inseparable and work together. One cannot use one without also using the other. Hence for my array distribution I need to create the array datatype in MPI with an `MPI_TYPE_CREATE_DARRAY` call, called for example 'subarray', AND to declare a standard Fortran array called 'buffer' for example, of the same dimension? Then I can `MPI_BCAST(buffer,1,subarray,master,cartesian_comm,ierror)`

Comment: What about accesssing to the data contained in 'buffer' from one process now? Should I use buffer(i,j,k) or original_array(i,j,k)? Which one works?

Comment: If I may ask a question again (sorry but I am a bit lost atm). I have been looking for the answer for hours but I keep finding different results that are (1,1,1) or (0,0,0): What is the starting coordinate in a Cartesian topology? I know it exists ways to get it using the rank of the considered process like `MPI_CART_COORD` but I cannot compile my code yet because it is still imcomplete and contains some mistakes. Thank you for your help. By the way thank you to have notice the bug.

Comment: If you feel I've answered your question, you can mark it as accepted. It's probably best if you open new questions for your other questions, it's getting a bit off-topic. Somebody might be able to answer it faster too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your last question: custom MPI datatypes need to be declared by all processes, not just the master node. This also goes for collective communications, like your `MPI_BCAST`, so you should move the call to `BCAST_PARAM` outside of the `if(rank == master)` block.

For your first question, your best bet is to do some empirical testing. It's difficult to say what will be faster for your actual use case, as it will also depend on how many times you communicate data and the details of the machine(s) you are running on.

MPI datatypes are only used in MPI routines for communicating data. If you want to package several Fortran variables together, the easiest way is to make a Fortran derived type that matches the MPI datatype. Here's what it would look like for your case:

```
! For kind=REAL64, more portable than kind=8
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env

type parameter_read_type
   integer                    :: nmin
   integer                    :: dout
   integer                    :: nmax
   integer                    :: ncellsmax
   integer, dimension(3)      :: ncells
   integer, dimension(3)      :: ns
   real(REAL64)               :: dt
   real(REAL64), dimension(3) :: del
end type parameter_read_type
```

You can then declare new variables as this type, and access the components with the `%` operator:

```
type(parameter_read_type) :: buffer

if (rank == master) call readParams(buffer)

call MPI_BCAST(buffer, 1, PARAMETER_READ, master, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierror)

...

subroutine readParams(read_parameters)
  type(parameter_read_type), intent(out) :: read_parameters

  read_parameters%nmin = ...
  read_parameters%ncells(1) = ...

  ...

end subroutine readParams
```

Creating a Fortran type like this will also let you pass around arrays of `parameter_read_type`:

```
type(parameter_read_type), dimension(2) :: buffer2

call readParams(buffer2(1))
call readParams(buffer2(2))

call MPI_BCAST(buffer2, 2, PARAMETER_READ, master, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierror)
```